# jquery remove selected value from textbox

Tags: jquery

```
<input class="y" id="imploding_feature3" type="hidden" name="product_labels_module[3][manual_products]" value=",,,,62,108,,45,">


<input class="y" id="imploding_feature4" type="hidden" name="product_labels_module[4][manual_products]" value=",,,,45,78,,26,">
```

I would like to get the value inputted from the user and then delete the value. For example, user enter value 45 then it will remove all 45 in textbox but other value will remind ,how can i do it using jquery??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the output of this demo, I think it does what you want.

**Updated script**:

```js
$('#removeProduct').on('click', function() {
 var input = $('#productId').val();
    
    // loop through each imploding_feature and remove value if exist
    $('input[id^="imploding_feature"]').each(function(ndx, elem) {
     var values = $(elem).val();
        console.log('before =', values);
        var valuesarray = values.split(',').map(function(val, ndx) {
         return (val === input)?'':val;
     }).join(',');
        $(elem).val(valuesarray);
        console.log('after =', valuesarray);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="productId" value="">
<button id="removeProduct">
remove product id
</button>
<input class="y" id="imploding_feature3" type="hidden" name="product_labels_module[3][manual_products]" value=",,,,62,108,,45,">


<input class="y" id="imploding_feature4" type="hidden" name="product_labels_module[4][manual_products]" value=",,,,45,78,,26,">
```

Comment: this code work for me, but my other text box will follow change,i chg edit my question abit

Comment: assume that id unique , how can i check this 2 field?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#imploding_featurel').on('keyup', function(e) {
  // enter
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    // get the value
    var value = $(this).val()

    // empty this
    $(this).val('').html('')
  }
})
```

listen to `keyup`/`keypress`.
Maybe you can add one button to add `click` listener.

Comment: i want only delete the value 45 , how can i do that?

Comment: If you need to target a specific value or values to clear means either logic like and if statement for a couple values or regular expression if you need to clear many specific values.

Comment: Use regex. `var value = $(this).val().replace(/\d/g, ''); $(this).val(value)`

Comment: Maybe `.replace('45', '')`, but I think this is not your question. @ChHong

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jquery to do this. Just use straight JS to set the field value of that element to equal an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my sample:

```
    // assign the value in a variable.
    var textValue = $("#inputSample").val(); 
    // this will remove the value in your input element.
    $("#inputSample").val("");
```

the **textValue** variable has the value of the input element.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming u want to keep the values in an array. So let's create an values array to hold the values. Then for each value change of the field we just store the array and empty it

```
var values=[];
  $(document).ready(function(){

    //create a value container array


    $('#imploding_feature1').change(function(e) {
      values.push($(this).val());
      $(this).val('');
  });
});
```